# PHP require failing to open stream

Tags: php, hyperlink, require

I am struggling trying to figure out why my `require` path link is not working.

My folder setup is the following:

```
Main domain on server test.example.com.

public_html -> test.example.com -> PHPMailer -> PHPMailerAutoload.php
```

Since the main domain is test.example.com, I am putting test.example.com in the path url. I have to do this for any link on the site (it was a setup mistake, but I haven't changed it yet).

The way I am trying to access this folder is below:

```
require 'test.example.com/test.example.com/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

I get the following errors:

```
Warning: require(test.example.com/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/example/public_html/test.example.com/php/newsletterSend.php on line 4

Warning: require(test.example.com/test.example.com/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/example/public_html/test.example.com/php/newsletterSend.php on line 4

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'test.example.com/test.example.com/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/example/public_html/test.example.com/php/newsletterSend.php on line 4
```

I need the link to be an absolute path because the file will be used in different folders.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try using the chdir: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php. With this function you can set the current directory to the current folder. So in your case it would be: chdir(\__DIR__);

Comment: In the script you wish to require the phpmailer, do an `echo __DIR__;` ... and see if anything appears to be not what you expected. From the looks of it, you can traverse from a script in one of those sub folders, like `require __DIR__.'/../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';`

Comment: @IncredibleHat I tried what you recommended and it seems to be working. Thanks for the suggestion. Would this work on subfolders too? For instance, I have been trying this on the index page. What if I was on subfolder/example ?

Comment: If you are deeper, you would then need two `../` like `__DIR__.'/../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'`. If you were in the same general area, then you wouldn't need any `../`. Its just path travel notation. Generally, I use `__DIR__` because I always know where all files are from each other. I personally never hard-burn in a servers root path to the web directory, because... well... once you have to move a site a few times and cannot rely on php include path being setup right ..... it's just easier lol.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Is there a way so that I don't have to change the file path? That is why I was trying the absolute path. The require path link is in a file that will be used in different folders.

Comment: If you can figure out the absolute path, then that will work. Just know if you move anything, it can break if you don't go changing that absolute path in all your files that need phpmailer. I cannot be sure what exactly your absolute path is from the image.

Comment: The path of the php file with the include will never change. The thing that changes is the location of where I am trying to get the file. So, looking at the picture: under test.example.com is where my main files are that I got this to work. Then, you will see a `solutions` folder. This is the other location that I will be making a call to the php file (ajax call).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your php is in a directory above the phpMailer folder.. so i think the path would be "../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"

you can use absolute paths if its simpler:

```
/home/foo/public_html/test.example.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php
```

or relative paths if you know where you're starting!

```
../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php
```

Comment: That's the thing. I have even tried the relative path for testing and it comes up with the same error. I'm not sure what is going on. Is there anything else that I can share that would help?

Comment: stupid question - but are you sure the file is there, and you're pointing to the exactly right name, with case senstive file paths?

Comment: Yes, it is there. I got it working with IncredibleHat's suggestion, but I ultimately need an absolute path that works with files in different folders.